# How to print on a previous line in Java?

Tags: java

Desired:

The first coordinate is (input1, input2).

What I Get:

The first coordinate is (input1

, input2

).

The code I used:

```
Scanner Narwhal = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("The first coordinate value is (");
double x = Narwhal.nextDouble();
System.out.print(", ");
double y = Narwhal.nextDouble();
System.out.print(").");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing input and output, and you validated your inputs with <return>... Or?

Comment: Your input is mixed with your output.  Do one then the other if you don't want them mixed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print it all out at once using `System.out.printf`.  This assumes you've moved the `nextDouble` calls *before* your print statement.

```
System.out.printf("The first coordinate value is (%0.1f, %0.1f).", x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the values from a user's input and after that you should print. You are mixing input and output.

You need something like this:

```
Scanner Narwhal = new Scanner(System.in);

double x = Narwhal.nextDouble();
double y = Narwhal.nextDouble();

System.out.print("The first coordinate value is (" + x);
System.out.print(", " + y);
System.out.print(").");
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not print the variables:

```
System.out.print("The first coordinate value is (");
double x = Narwhal.nextDouble();
System.out.print(x + ", ");
double y = Narwhal.nextDouble();
System.out.print(y + ").");
```